# How to make a loading icon

Tags: css, css-animations, font-awesome, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI and trying to create an animated icon for example with the spinner icon.
https://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html#spinners

With font-awesome it is pretty simple, as described here : https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/animating-icons*

Is there an equivalent of `fa-spin` for semantic UI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class called [**`loader`**](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/loader.html) out of the box but you can always use custom CSS like below for your purposes.

```
.loading {
  animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Loading styles */

.loading {
  animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

/* Additional styles for snippet */
.ui.container {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/components/icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://semantic-ui.com//stylesheets/docs.css">
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui raised segment">
    <div class="ui doubling five column grid center aligned">

      <div class="column"><i class="circle notch icon huge loading"></i></div>
      <div class="column"><i class="cog icon huge loading"></i></div>
      <div class="column"><i class="compass icon huge loading"></i></div>
      <div class="column"><i class="compass outline icon huge loading"></i></div>
      <div class="column"><i class="crosshairs icon huge loading"></i></div>
      <div class="column"><i class="life ring icon huge loading"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: In fact, the building class seems to be "loading" and not "loader" : https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/deb275d2d5fe9a522a0b7bd8b6b6a1c939552718/dist/components/icon.css#L58

Comment: That's a coincidence!

Comment: That's a coincidence that you called your css class "loading", but in my case, the semantic ui "loading" class does the job. This is the solution I will use

Answer (score 0):

At current version of Semantic UI (in 2022) you can just add "loading" class for icon`s i-tag:

Static icon:

```
<i class="cog icon"></i>
```

Rotating icon :

```
<i class="loading cog icon"></i>
```

( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/semantic-ui-icon-loading-state/ )